# curl scrape page if fail

Tags: php, curl

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$site = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$site = curl_exec($site);

if(FALSE){//DO SOMETHING}
```

I try to use curl scrape page, however I need to detect if url is fail.

1. question, which will be better?

   curl or file_get_contents($url)?

Comment: Start from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps its easier to do it without `file_get_contents`.

```
$siteContent = file_get_contents("http://example.com");

if($siteContent) {
   // do something
}
```

if you need more options or a post then you have to use curl. For this you have to set the option `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini to `On`.

Comment: I have tried file get contents, but I want to try different method, and not sure which is better, whats different

Comment: Its much shorter. And you can't set so much options.

Comment: cURL calls are more useful when you want to make a post request, or have more options like Stony said

Answer (score 1):

You could use the http status code to check if it was a valid response:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$siteCurl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($siteCurl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$site = curl_exec($siteCurl);

$result = curl_exec($siteCurl );
$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($http_status != "200"){//DO SOMETHING}
```

See here for the http codes if you are unsure: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html